# RAM based file system that overflows to physical disk and maintains maximum I/O performance

Tags: tmpfs, ramdisk, file-management

I have an issue that seems to hit all the restrictions I have read about regarding tmpfs. I would be very happy to hear anyone's comments on a possible solution.
I have an application that generates a single large file as it runs. This file can grow to several GB.
During program execution the I/O operations to this file are intense and any pipeline makes a significant performance impact on the running application.
To attempt speed up I created a tmpfs, this works wonderfully and performance is dramatically improved. However when the tmpfs runs out of space (~50%) physical RAM usage, the application crashes. No surprise there.
The data generated by the application is only needed when the process creating the data is complete. Therefore, what I need is a ram based file system that will fill with data coming from the application. When this ram based file system is full, it pushes the complete contents of the ram based tmpfs to physical disk, entirely freeing the RAM, and then continues to accept data from the application filling RAM again. Thereby maintaining minimum I/O pipeline delay for the application for the vast majority of time it is running.
When the process is complete I would hope to find a single large file that partially exists on disk and partially in RAM.
Any ideas?